# GitBook generates epub with duplicate headings

Tags: epub, calibre

I have ebook in markdown files and use GitBook for generating epub file. Like usual, chapters are defined in SUMMARY.md and chapter files begins with a headings (the same like in summary):

```
Title of the chapter
====================
```

GitBook uses Calibre's tool [ebook-convert](https://manual.calibre-ebook.com/generated/en/ebook-convert.html) to generate epub files what will have html files with title section like:

```
  <body class="calibre">

<div class="page">

        <h1 class="book-chapter2" id="calibre_toc_2">Title of the chapter</h1>
        <div class="section">
            <h1 id="příběh-první" class="calibre17">Title of the chapter</h1>
```

First h1 have `display: none` in CSS, so will not be visible in most readers, but some of them ignores it and renders heading twice.

Is there a way, to configure GitBook or epub-convert to not add second heading and keep table of contents working?